# How to prepopulate a form with specific data on click of a 'EDIT' button in JavaScript? (without using any database)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am using simple JavaScript code to submit a form and storing the form data into an array in the form of objects and later showing the data on click of a button. I also have provided two buttons -'EDIT' and 'DELETE' for each elements while showing the data in tabular form under 'Action' header.

I can pass the corresponding ids to those methods to perform edit and delete operation on specific entries/object and based on that I want to keep data in final array and want to show them after the operation.

However I have done the 'delete' functionality but I could not get any lead to implement the 'EDIT' button functionality. 
I want to know- is it possible to prepopulate the form with data available and make the changes and again save it back when I click on edit button?

Note: I am not using any database connection for this. Here in the below code I am storing the objects in **dataArray**

sample form object- I am storing dataArray after submit:

```
0: CreateUser
description: "I am Web developer"
email: "test@gmail.com"
english: "english"
gender: "Male"
hindi: "hindi"
id: "12312"
name: "test"
othersLang: "others"
role: "dev"
```

Please have a look at it ---

```js
function getEmployeeDetails() {
  let totalLength = userArray.length;

  if (totalLength === 0) {
    alert("No user Data Found");
    return;
  }

  let tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
  tbody.innerHTML = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
    let tr = `<tr id=` + userArray[i].id + `>`;
    tr +=
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].id +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].name +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].email +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].gender +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].role +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].english +
      userArray[i].hindi +
      userArray[i].othersLang +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].description +
      "</td>" +
      `<td class="table-data">
      <button onclick="deleteUser(` +
      userArray[i].id +
      `)">Delete</button> || <button onclick="editUser( ` +
      userArray[i].id +
      `)">Edit</button>
      </td>`;

    tbody.innerHTML += tr;
  }
}

function deleteUser(id) {
  console.log('ID',id);
  userArray = userArray.filter(x => x.id === id);
  console.log("aftre", userArray);
  let elem = document.getElementById(id);
  elem.remove();
  return userArray;
}
function editUser(id) {
  console.log("edit", id);//prints corresponding id
}
```

I am not sure if this can be achieved or not.

Any suggestion on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, but if you're trying to prepopulate your page without the use of any database, you could use a file with some json data in it. 
see [JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)
Or you could pretty much hardcode it into your page on an on-load event.

On a side note, if you know you're not going to work with Internet Explorer you could use the **find()** function instead of the **filter()**, as **find()** will stop its iteration on the array once it finds the FIRST occurrence of whatever you passed in its function, and **filter()** will just keep going. 
Seeing as you're trying to get data using a unique ID, it might be better to use it instead :)
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: This is not something I am looking for. I have already stated all the details.If you need any other things please specify it

Comment: By "pre-populating the form" do you mean that once you click on a user, its Edit form is populated by the user's data?

Comment: Yes. I want to pre populate all the fields in the form